# Ubuntu 16.04 will not install alongside Windows 7, but 14.04 will

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, partitioning, 16.04

I have an Acer Predator G3610 desktop with Windows 7 - the last computer I have without Ubuntu as either dual-boot or sole OS.  I shrunk the Windows partition so there's a good 300GB of unallocated space on the 1TB hard drive.  I popped the Ubuntu 16.04 live cd in, click Install, and get this:

16.04 install attempt:
[image: 16.04 install attempt]

Ubuntu detects my Win7 install but will not give me the option to install Ubuntu alongside it.  So, just for a goof, I pop in my old 14.04 live cd and get... this :

[image: 14.04 install attempt]  the option to install alongside Win7. What gives? And yes, I checked to make sure there wasn't any funny UEFI issue -Both liveCDs boot from BIOS just like the Windows partition.

I have half a mind to just install 14.04 and upgrade later at this point, but I'd really like figure out why 16.04 hates my Windows partition so much.

Comment: Did you try selecting "something else?" I installed with the mini.iso installer rather than a live CD so I'm not sure of the differences, but there could be an off chance that 16~ has a slightly different interface there than 14~ (although it's been the same for just as long as I can remember... that's probably at least a good week or two! :)

Comment: I just installed 16.04 today on a system that already had a Windows 7 installation.  (But of course I used the "Something Else" option to provide me with complete control of the process.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out on my own. The "Install Ubuntu inside of Windows" on 14.04.3 is some old Wubi option.  As for 16.04, I neglected to mention earlier that before booting up the LiveCD, I resized the Windows partition and left the space unallocated. I did not use the Gparted program to reallocate the unused space before clicking the install ubuntu icon.  Well, after frustrating myself over and over agin trying to make the "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows" option magically appear, I started Gparted and used it to create the Ubuntu partition and swap file - plan was to use the "Do something else" option afterwards. But after I created those partitions and clicked Install Ubuntu, the Install Alongside option magically appeared.  So lesson learned - the Install alongside option will not appear if all the installer sees is a Windows partition and unallocated space.

Comment: To ping another user use @Theusername  or comment on their post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had installed ubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows7 and did not see any such option either. According to me this has to do with Windows7 and not Ubuntu. You can use the something else option to install Ubuntu.

First delete the partition you wish to use for ubuntu in windows disk management and then proceed to this link: http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2014/05/install-ubuntu-1404-alongside-windows.html

P.S. a personal request do tag me after installation of 16.04 as I had faced problems while its installation and grub repeatedly failed to install